# Is this program actually valid

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[1000];
    scanf("word%s", word);
    printf("%s", word);
}
```

It seems that when I input any string, as long as I type out "word" first, I get proper output.
But is this program actually valid

Comment: In theory, yes, but I would just use %s because then the user doesn't have to type word first. Although idk what happens if you try to type more than 1000 chars, maybe scanf somehow has protection against that?

Comment: Why should it not be a _valid_ program? To get a proper answer to your question you should better explain why you think it would not be a valid program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles and therefore is valid from a syntax perspective. It's also fine in order to check that a prefix is used.

However, there are at least two ways to get undefined behaviour:

- `scanf` might store more than 1000 characters (read 999 and one for the final `\0`)
- `scanf` might read none if the input does not start with `"word"`

You should therefore check the result of `scanf`, initialize `word`, and also limit the maximum number of characters that `scanf` reads:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[1000] = {0};

    int ret = scanf("word%999s", word);

    if ( ret == 1 ) {
        printf("%s", word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this program is valid ,but you have to be careful about buffer overflow , which means if user input more than 999 chars this will lead to undefined behavior , so I suggest this:

`scanf("word%999s", word);`

also as you said `as long as I type out "word" first` ,otherwise `char word[1000]` will be uninitialized.